# Fill Html.BeginForm route values with Html page or Javascript values (Not by Model values)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In asp.net mvc 5 there is a values on page, that user is entered or somehow it calculated by javascript. I need to put it in Html.BeginForm in section TO and FROM. The code sample is below:

MyPage.cshtml

```
<input id="datepickerFrom" value="31/12/2017" title="datepicker" />
<input id="datepickerTo" value="30/06/2018" title="datepicker" />
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "DashBoard", new inputDates { from = "", to = "" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
     <input type="submit" value="Export to Excel" class="button" />
}
```

Controller.ActionName

```
public ActionResult ActionName(inputDates dates)
{
     //some actions 
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(555, "Everything is OK");
}
```

Class inputDates

```
public class inputDates
{
     public DateTime? from { get; set; }
     public DateTime? to { get; set; }
}
```

I found a lot of answers that are using Model, but my values a are not from model. I don't know  how to take values from html element or javascript values.

Thank you for help.

Comment: For a start, your inputs need to be inside the form. Then they need `name` attributes to match the model properties (i.e. `name="from"` etc). And your `new inputDates { from = "", to = "" }` in the `BeginForm()` make no sense (delete that)

Comment: Your `BeginForm` overload doesn't makes sense (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492719(v=vs.118)#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29)). Use viewmodel properties and other helpers to pass those  required elements.

Comment: Hi below link can help you [How to send javascript var in Html beginform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488882/how-to-send-javascript-var-in-html-beginform-in-mvc3)

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, zalt you have to put "from" and "to" into form tag and set your html input controls name attribute same as your model property it bind with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @model inputDates //do proper import of class here.

   @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "DashBoard", FormMethod.Post))
    {
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.from)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.to)
         <input type="submit" value="Export to Excel" class="button" />
    }
```

This should work, just see if MVC automatically converts text to datetime or not. I have not used this in long time so my memory is hazy on this one.
Also, read about Model Binding in MVC.

Some Links 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/introduction-to-model-binding-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol